# Hta Application + Python

Tags: html, python

Мне нужно узнать подробно как использовать питон в hta приложении

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Установите [ActivePython](https://www.activestate.com/activepython) или [PyWin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)
2. Напишите код HTA

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
       <HTA:APLICATION>

       <title>Python Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <button onclick="say_hi()">Нажми меня</button>

       <script language="python">
         def say_hi():
           alert("from python");
       </script>
     </body>    
   </html>
   ```
3. Запустите

Comment: А сам питон должен быть установлен? А можно как-то сделать чтобы эти файлы питонов таскать рядом с hta файлом тоесть чтобы пользователь просто скачал sfx архив с hta и всё запустилось без установки python на пк?

Comment: Нет, это невозможно. Чтобы Python можно было использовать как язык сценариев в HTA, в системе должен быть зарегистрирован соответствующий ActiveX-компонент.